# Sinon Spy never called but it should be

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, spy

### Problem

I'm testing a custom redux middleware using Jest and SinonJS and more precisely I want to test if some functions are called on special conditions inside the middleware.

I use SinonJS for creating the spies and I run my tests with Jest. I initialised the spies for the specific functions I want to track and when I check if the spies has been called, the spies has not been even if it should be (manually tested).

### Code

Here is the middleware I want to test :

```js
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import setAuthorizationToken from './setAuthorizationToken';

let cookies = new Cookies();

export const bindTokenWithApp = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    // Select the token before action
    const previousToken = getToken(store.getState());
    // Dispatch action
    const result = next(action);
    // Select the token after dispatched action
    const nextToken = getToken(store.getState());

    if (previousToken !== nextToken) {
        if (nextToken === '') {
            setAuthorizationToken(false);
            cookies.remove(SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, COOKIE_OPTIONS);
        } else {
            cookies.set(SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, nextToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS);
            setAuthorizationToken(nextToken);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Here is my actual test

```js
import { bindTokenWithApp } from './middleware';
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import sinon, { assert } from 'sinon';
import setAuthorizationToken from './setAuthorizationToken';

describe('bindTokenWithApp', () => {
    const next = jest.fn();
    const action = jest.fn();
    let cookies = new Cookies();

    it('removes cookies when there is no token', () => {
        // My actual not working spies
        const cookieSpy = sinon.spy(cookies.remove);
        const authSpy = sinon.spy(setAuthorizationToken);

        // Stub for the specific case. This code works, 
        // I console.logged in the middleware and I'm getting the below values
        const getState = sinon.stub();
        getState.onFirstCall().returns({ auth: { token: 'a token' } });
        getState.onSecondCall().returns({ auth: { token: '' } });
        const store = { getState: getState };

        bindTokenWithApp(store)(next)(action);

        assert.calledOnce(cookieSpy);
        assert.calledOnce(authSpy);
        // Output : AssertError: expected remove to be called once but was called 0 times
        // AssertError: expected setAuthorizationToken to be called once but was called 0 times

        cookieSpy.restore(); // <= This one works
        authSpy.restore(); // TypeError: authSpy.restore is not a function 

  });
});
```

I've read SinonJS doc and a few StackOverFlow posts but without solutions. I also can't call `authSpy.restore();`. I think I do not initialise spies the right way and I'm misunderstanding a concept in SinonJS but I can't find which one !

> The setAuthorizationToken signature is
>   (alias) const setAuthorizationToken: (token: any) => void
>   import setAuthorizationToken
>
> I think it's a classical module so I can't figure out why I struggle with `authSpy.restore();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two spies you have actually have two different fixes, both with the same underlying problem. `sinon.spy(someFunction)` doesn't actually wrap `someFunction` itself, it returns a spy for it but doesn't perform any replacement.

For the first spy, there exists a shorthand to automatically wrap an object method: `sinon.spy(cookie, 'remove')` should do what you need.

For the second spy, it is more complicated as you need to wrap the spy around the default export of `setAuthorizationToken`. For that you will need something like proxyquire. Proxyquire is a specialized require mechanism that allows you to replace imports with your desired test methods. Here's a brief of what you'll need to do:

```
const authSpy = sinon.spy(setAuthorizationToken);
bindTokenWithApp = proxyquire('./middleware', { './setAuthorizationToken': authSpy});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've tried the two solutions but none works. I understand the underlying problem, for the first spy I have now in my test : `sinon.spy(cookies, 'remove'); assert.calledOnce(cookies.remove);` but with the same output. For the second spy, I've tried with proxyquire and jest.mock (from this [article](https://madole.xyz/mocking-relative-dependencies-in-jest-with-jest-mock/) but without success). I can't assert `bindTokenWithApp = proxyquire…` because it's read-only from import. And when I assert `const bindTokenWithApp =…` I can't execute it because it's not a function…